# How to sync iPhone X that has never been synced before with iTunes without losing any of the data?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

How do I access iPhone backups on my iPhone when I connect it to iTunes, when the only options are:

- continue from backup, which is a backup of an iPhone I am still using, or
- start as new iPhone?

I am using two iPhones - the one in question hasn't been synced to iTunes, and now, whenever I connect it to my laptop I’m worried it will delete everything and start from new - iTunes gives me two options:

- continue from backup from my primary iPhone (still in use) or
- start as new iPhone.

How do I access my iCloud backups to ensure I can sync my new iPhone to my iTunes without having to start as a new iPhone?